# Saving frequently used expressions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-2, expression, select-by-attribute

Is there any way to save frequently used expressions in the selection or field calculator dialogs? Obviously I can cut and paste them into a file where I might save them, but I mean within the context of QGIS like you can do in ArcMap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment.  There is a [ticket](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6091) for it, and assigned to me no less :)

It was in my original plans just never got around to it.

I don't think I will have time for 2.2 but maybe 2.4.

Answer (score 4):

This has been possible for many many releases by now:

[image]