# How to re-use an expression, stored as a string, in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, function

As discussed in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83120/is-it-possible-to-save-frequently-used-expressions-in-qgis), QGIS automatically saves *recently used* expressions in the field calculator. But recently used expressions are deleted after a while. Sometimes I need to re-use an expression that I used a while ago, and it's no longer available.

**So I needed a way to store expressions for re-use in the Field Calculator at a much later time.**

The method I figured out is to store the expression as in a text field. When I need to re-use the expression, I copy it from the attribute table into the Field Calculator. Here's what that looks like with a simple example:

[image]

Of course it's trivial to remember and re-enter the expression in this example. I would use this method with much more complicated expressions, such as `"Population"/$area*3.58701e-8/"Population"`, which calculates population density (people per square mile) after first converting square feet to square miles.

---

**Now I'm looking for a better way than manually copying the expression**. It seems like there should be a way in the Field Calculator to take the field name as input, interpret it as an expression, and output the result of that expression. Here's what I've tried so far:

Just using the field name outputs the formula as a string.

[image]

**Is there a function that will force the Field Calculator to interpret a string as an expression?** By comparison to the expressions `to_real()` and `as_string()`, I'm thinking it would be something like `as_expression()` or `as_formula()`. So the output of `as_expression('$area')` would be the calculated area of the polygon feature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question almost as soon as I posted it. The function I was looking for is called `eval`.

> **function eval**
>
> Evaluates an expression which is passed in a string. Useful to expand dynamic parameters passed as context variables or fields.
>
> **Syntax** eval(expression)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> *expression* an expression string
>
> **Examples**
>
> - `eval(''nice'')` → 'nice'
> - `eval(@expression_var)` → [whatever the result of evaluating @expression_var might be...]

So for my example where an expression is stored as a string in a field called "Expression", use this in the Field Calculator:

```
eval("Expression")
```

Comment: Hit that green check mark :)